# How to handle client certificate in Ajax call in Phonegap

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, ssl

I am trying to access https web service call in Ajax in our phonegap application. It is giving me below error while working. Client certificate has been installed in Android device.

```
ERROR:aw_contents_client_bridge.cc(210)] Client certificate request cancelled
12-16 14:26:39.502: E/chromium(5859): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(849)] handshake failed; returned 0, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
12-16 14:26:40.558: E/chromium(5859): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(849)] handshake failed; returned 0, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
12-16 14:26:41.584: E/chromium(5859): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(849)] handshake failed; returned 0, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
12-16 14:26:42.672: E/chromium(5859): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(849)] handshake failed; returned 0, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
12-16 14:26:42.715: D/CordovaLog(5859)
```

Comment: Improve your question detail and maybe change `https://` to `http://`. Seems like ssl certificate is invalid or self-signed.

Comment: This is user level certificate and we want to implement 2FA authentication. I can see user certificate in my device but when I use phonegap application (Ajax https call) it give me above mentioned error.

Comment: Yes it is self signed certificate. How to use this self sign certificate in Phonegap Ajax webservice call

Comment: @user1421255, hi. have you found solution?